# Tensorflow Keras Model working on CPU but doesn't work with GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-2

I am beginner in `Tensorflow` and `Keras`.

I ran the code on my CPU with the following configuration and it works completely fine:

```
Tensorflow version: 1.10.0
tf.keras version 2.1.6
```

But when I try to run the code on a GPU server with the following configuration:

```
Tensorflow(GPU) version: 1.8.0
tf.keras version 2.1.5
```

I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Keras3 tut.py", line 127, in <module>
    history = model.fit(ds_train, steps_per_epoch = 1500, epochs = 15)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/training.py", line 1143, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/training.py", line 765, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 150, in standardize_input_data
    data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 150, in <listcomp>
    data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 88, in standardize_single_array
    elif x.ndim == 1:
AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

The code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tensorflow import FixedLenFeature

featdef = {
    'train/image': FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype= tf.string),
    'train/label': FixedLenFeature(shape = [], dtype = tf.int64)
}

def _parse_record (example_proto, clip = False):
    ex = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, featdef)

    im = tf.decode_raw(ex['train/image'], tf.uint8)
    im = tf.reshape(im, (28,28,3))
    im = tf.cast(im, tf.float32)*(1./255)

    #label = (ex['train/label'])
    label = tf.one_hot(ex['train/label'], 2)
    print(label)
    print(im)
    return im, label

batch_size = 50
ds_train = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('/home/mudit/AI/TFrecord_Datasets/Melanoma_training_uint8.tfrecords').map(_parse_record)
ds_train = ds_train.repeat().shuffle(1000).batch(batch_size)

IM_SIZE = 28

image_input = tf.keras.Input(shape = (IM_SIZE, IM_SIZE, 3), name = 'input_layer')

conv_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3,3),
                              padding = 'same',
                              activation = 'relu')(image_input)

conv1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(padding = 'same')(conv_1)


conv_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3,3), padding = 'same',
                               activation = 'relu')(conv_1)

conv_flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(conv_2)

fc_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(28,
                             activation='relu')(conv_flat)
fc_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(fc_1)

fc_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(28,
                             activation='relu')(fc_1)

fc_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4)(fc_2)

label_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,
                                       activation='softmax',
                                       name='label')(fc_2)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = image_input, outputs = [label_output])

print(model.summary())

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(ds_train, steps_per_epoch = 500, epochs = 8)
```

On the GPU, it gives error at `model.fit()`.

The code is working completely fine on my CPU but not on the GPU server. 
Is it possible that the problem is because of the version difference? I tried finding the solutions for it but to no avail.

EDIT 1:
I tried running the same code on my PC using the same configuration as GPU server (Tensorflow 1.8.0 Keras 2.1.5) and it gives me exactly the same error. So, it's definitely a version problem. I reckon, there must've been some modifications in the tf.data API but can't find out what.

Comment: Additional info: When I try to print the dataset using the following code
`tensor = ds_train.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
with tf.Session() as session:
    print(session.run(tensor))`

It gives an AttributeError: 'MapDataset' object has no attribute 'make_oneshot_iterator'

Comment: The first thing that pops in my mind is the difference between Tensoflow versions on your machine and the GPU server. If the code runs on your machine, try updating packages on the server to the same versions that are on your local machine.

Comment: I don't have the permission to update the packages on the server as it is university's server. Should I try to run the same code on my PC with the `Tensorflow 1.8.0` and `Keras 2.1.5`?

Comment: That would be the next step, yes.

Comment: I tried running the same code on my PC using the same configuration as GPU (`Tensorflow 1.8.0`  `Keras 2.1.5`) and it gives me exactly the same error. So, it's definitely a version problem. How should I modify my code to make it compatible with `Tensorflow 1.8.0`

Comment: I don't know specifically why this error occurs but at least, you managed to troubleshoot the problem and see it's source. Go to the tensorlfow documentation and select version of tensorflow 1.8.0. From there, check the classes and methods that throw the errors. Maybe the methods are called differently or they take different attributes.

Comment: Thanks you very much